# Bootstrap modal won't close in Laravel project

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a Laravel project. After submitting the forms, if the validators are ok, it pops up a bootstrap modal, like the following.

```
@php
   if(session('message_success')) {
       echo "<script>
                $('#thank-you').modal('show');
             </script>";
   }
@endphp
```

The modal shows accordingly, but for some reason, I can't close it.

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal" id="thank-you" tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="anyotherlabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
                        style="float: right;"></button>
                <div class="text-center py-3">
                    <h3 class="title-form-catalogue">The Club is thankful
                        for your request!</h3>
                    <p>Take a look at your e-mail to get access to the prestigious
                        information you required.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking outside of the modal closes it, but clicking the button does nothing.

In some cases, I have read that the fade class seems to be preventing the modal from closing, but I'm not sure this is the issue here. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: clicking out of the modal don't close? by the button?

Comment: You can try this `<button type="button" class="btn-close" style="float: right;" onclick="$('#thank-you').modal('hide');"></button>`

Comment: @sta I tried your approach and it did not work. It seems like such a simple problem, but for some reason it is taking me hours to figure it out.

Comment: @Prospero yes, clicking out of the modal will close, it´s just the button that doesn´t work.

Comment: Is there any error log in your dev tools?

Comment: @JimishFotariya No errors. 

Just tried this I it didn't work:

 $("#closeButton").click(function () {
    $('.modal.in').modal('hide');
});

Comment: I also tried:

```
$("#closeButton").click(function () {
    $("#sheet").css("display", "none");
});
```

AIt did hide the module but the website froze and I couldn´t scroll and see the page normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. I added a "closeButton" Id to the button, and then used the following code:

```
$("#closeButton").click(function () {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('body').css('padding-right', '');
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    $('#thank-you').hide();
});
```